# jQuery UI datepicker - Date Range - #to - set first month to display where numberOfMonths = 3 (it defaults to selected days month)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-range

Hi, I have a 2 textboxes (`#from` and `#to`), with a date-range between them.
[DateRange Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range)

E.g. `#from` I select `10 October 2014`
(The current popups show October,November,December)

Now at this stage the `#to` textbox has no value, when you click on the textbox, it shows from `October 2014` which is absolutely perfect this is what I need. (I know this is because of the code in on `onClose` event as in the hyperlink).

The problem is that if I select e.g. `December 2014` now in `#to`, and it closes, and I open `#to` again, it then shows December,January,February.

The requirement is that the user needs to not look forward in #to but he needs to see that the range was from October 2014 to December 2014 - and thus needs to see the three months on the screen as October,November, December and not the default 3 months that the jQuery UI Datepicker shows after a date has been selected.

Is it possible to set the first month that a 3 month calender has to display?

Comment: Could you post your code or set up a jsFiddle and explain more precisely which restriction do you expect in the #to. E.g. 10 October is selected on the #from, do you want the #to to be restrected to 10 October - 10 January (that is to say selectedDate + 3 month) ? You can restrict the minDate/maxDate in the #to based on the value selected in the #from